# A good screen mirroring app for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-recommendation, android

I am wondering whether there is any screen mirroring software that will work with my non-rooted Android phone using 4.4.2.

Comment: Do you mean mirroring android screen to ubuntu ?

Comment: yes  i do mean that

Comment: Is the question still up ?

Answer (score 4):

In that case, consider try [SevenSquare](https://github.com/yangh/sevensquare#seven-sqaure). A tool used to view a mirror screen of your Android device on the PC, used for demostration, debuging, and so on. even you can click on the mirror screen as you touch on the device panel.

> Major:
>
> - Click and swipe on the screen (so you can unlock screen by swipe)
> - Virtual menu/home/back key on the UI
> - QWERTY key support (just type via your keyboard)
> - Auto connect to your device when plug in
> - Click on window to wakeup the device (emulate power key press event)
> - Support both Android ICS and Jelly Bean. Froyo not full tested
> - Wrote in Qt 4.x, easily port to different desktop environment
>
> Minor:
>
> - Rotate view windows on demand (Press F12)
> - Virtual cursor (pointer anchor) on the UI
> - Auto resize to fit the screen resolution of the device
> - Zoom window as your wish and keep the ratio
> - Support customized 'screencap' for speeding up (RGBA32, RGB888, RGB565)
> - Auto enable compressed data transfer if 'minigzip' found on the host
> - 1~2FPS on MSM8625 device (1.2G dual core, 512M memory, 800x480)
>
> Non-feature:
>
> - Not support multi devices pluged in at the same time.
> - Not support screen recording as video
> - Not support screen shot as picture
>
> <sub>[Source](https://github.com/yangh/sevensquare#features)</sub>

According to its [GitHub](https://github.com/yangh/sevensquare#seven-sqaure) page, SevenSquare has been reportedly working on both Linux and Windows system.

#### Installing SevenSquare

Make sure you have ADB (Android Debug Bridge) tools installed on your system in order to install SevenSquare:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

SevenSquare based on [QT](https://qt.io), therefore you need to install these dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4
```

Now you can finally install SevenSquare:

```
wget https://github.com/yangh/sevensquare/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip && cd sevensquare-master
make && sudo make install
```

Make sure you have enabled **USB debugging** on your android device, otherwise navigate to Settings > Developer Tools > and enable **USB debugging**, then connect your android device to computer via USB cable.

To launch SevenSquare, run following command:

```
seven-square &
```

[image]

<sub>Image taken from [www.upubuntu.com](http://www.upubuntu.com)</sub>